# RESTful API Spring boot on AWS lambda has an error

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda

I'm making RESTful API Spring boot 3.2.4 on AWS lambda.

my handler code has an error. I know what it is, where it occur.

I don't know what to do.

I really appreciate if you help me.

let me show you my codes

this is error logs below :

```
2024-03-06T08:04:58.975Z ERROR 8 --- \[           main\] c.a.s.p.internal.LambdaContainerHandler  : Error while handling request
com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.InvalidRequestEventException: The incoming event is not a valid request from Amazon API Gateway or an Application Load Balancer
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsProxyHttpServletRequestReader.readRequest(AwsProxyHttpServletRequestReader.java:48) \~\[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M1.jar:na\]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsProxyHttpServletRequestReader.readRequest(AwsProxyHttpServletRequestReader.java:30) \~\[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M1.jar:na\]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:204) \~\[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M1.jar:na\]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:257) \~\[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M1.jar:na\]
at com.working.taxbill.Handler.TaxHandler.handleRequest(TaxHandler.java:58) \~\[task/:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) \~\[na:na\]
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:378) \~\[aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client-2.4.1-linux-aarch_64.jar:2.4.1\]
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:905) \~\[aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client-2.4.1-linux-aarch_64.jar:2.4.1\]
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:245) \~\[aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client-2.4.1-linux-aarch_64.jar:2.4.1\]
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:197) \~\[aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client-2.4.1-linux-aarch_64.jar:2.4.1\]
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.main(AWSLambda.java:187) \~\[aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client-2.4.1-linux-aarch_64.jar:2.4.1\]
```

and this is handler code :

```
public class TaxHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    private static final SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(TaxbillApplication.class);
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }

    public TaxHandler() {
        // we enable the timer for debugging. This SHOULD NOT be enabled in production.
        Timer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("Final string result: " + inputStream.toString());

        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}
```

and dependencies and profiles at pom.xml :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.74.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>shaded-jar</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>assembly-zip</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- select and copy only runtime dependencies to a temporary lib folder -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>zip-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src${file.separator}assembly${file.separator}bin.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <attach>false</attach>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

this is my SAM in AWS :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Serverless Application Model template describing your function.
Resources:
  myTaxBill:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 15
      Handler: com.working.taxbill.Handler.TaxHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java17
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      EphemeralStorage:
        Size: 512
      EventInvokeConfig:
        MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 21600
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 2
      FunctionUrlConfig:
        AuthType: NONE
        InvokeMode: BUFFERED
      PackageType: Zip
      Policies:
        - Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogGroup
              Resource: arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-2:730335486608:*
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
              Resource:
                - >-
                  arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-2:730335486608:log-group:/aws/lambda/myTaxBill:*
      SnapStart:
        ApplyOn: None
      Events:
        Api1:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /MyResource
            Method: ANY
        Api2:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
        Api3:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /MyResource
            Method: ANY
        Api4:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: POST
        Api5:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
      RuntimeManagementConfig:
        UpdateRuntimeOn: Auto
```

I tried dependency at pom.xml, changed code at TaxHandler.java

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot call your lamba through the function URL.
https://github.com/aws/serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot3

Check this link to get started and see what SAM create as resources in AWS. The problem does not come from your code. There is nothing to change in java/maven.

Comment: I show you SAM in AWS through editing my post. Can you check this?

Comment: How do you invoke your function ? The API gateway must have a specific URL that you can use, you can see it on the AWS console in your API Gateway